# Error: (JetPack Compose) Type 'TypeVariable(T)' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

I found an article where it describes how to make implementation of parallax view in LazyColumn and there is such a method:

```
@Composable
    fun ImageParallaxScroll() {
        val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
        val list = (0..1_000).map{ "Item $it" }.toList()

        val firstItemTranslationY: LazyListState by remember {
            derivedStateOf {
                when {
                    lazyListState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.isNotEmpty() && lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex == 0 -> lazyListState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset * .6f
                    else -> 0f
                }
            }
        }

            ...
    }
```

The problem is that the entire block of `remember` underline with a red line and such error comes:

```
Type 'TypeVariable(T)' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate
```

Can't understand what is problem here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Couple things I can see here...

**Firstly :**

You need to import :

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
```

Or import everything using :

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
```

This will import the extension operator function on `State<T>` which you are missing (from the SnapshotState.kt file).

The IDE seems to have a difficult time auto importing top level extension functions for some reason.

Not sure why its `inlined` but thats probably the reason for not just adding it to the `State<T>` interface and instead having the loose top level function, requiring the extra import.

**Secondly :**

I believe the return type by will `Float` not `LazyListState`.

So the function with imports would be (also remembering the list itself so its not recalculated in recomposition) :

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.rememberLazyListState
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.derivedStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember

@Composable
fun ImageParallaxScroll() {
    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
    val list = remember { (0..1_000).map{ "Item $it" }.toList() }

    val firstItemTranslationY: Float by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            when {
                lazyListState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.isNotEmpty() && lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex == 0 -> lazyListState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset * .6f
                else -> 0f
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: For me, it worked after importing the 

import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue

May be an IDE import issue..!!

Answer (score 0):

In your build.graddle **project level** Update compose version to the last one

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.4.0'
    }
}
```

and upgrade kotlin.android plugin version

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
```

}

it looks like a version compatibility trouble

Doing this could require update some implementation versions declared in build.gradle **app level**